# The summation of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, summation

Does this equation hold ?
$$\sum_{i}^{N}\sum_{j}^{N}\sum_{k}^{N}(A_i-A_j)(A_i-A_k) = C\sum_{i}^{N}\sum_{j}^{N}(A_i-A_j)^2$$

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: It's come from a paper of depth estimation. https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2283. Equation (1) and (2). Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Please, add this information to your question -- it may be closed for lack of relevant context otherwise.

Comment: It seems to be true with $C=\frac N2$. I recommend counting the number of occurrences of $A_m^2$ and $A_mA_n$ on both sides to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, introduce some notation:

$$S = \sum A_l$$
$$T = \sum A_l^2.$$

Now, the left hand side: do the innermost sum first, to get

$$\sum_i \sum_j (A_i - A_j) (N A_i - S).$$
Do the next inner sum, to get

$$\sum_i(NA_i - S)^2.$$

Finally, open the square to get

$$N^2 T - 2 N S^2 + N S^2 = N^2 T - N S^2$$

On the right hand side.

Do the inner sum to get

$$\sum_i (N A_i^2 - 2 A_i S + T).$$

Do the remaining sum to get $$N T - 2 S^2 + N T = 2 N T - 2 S^2,$$

So, Greg Martin is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help！